# Filesystems: Sending and receiving snapshots

Tags: lvm, zfs

From Wikipedia [ZFS Snapshots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Sending_and_receiving_snapshots)

> **Sending and receiving snapshots**
>
> ZFS file systems can be moved to other
>   pools, also on remote hosts over the network, as the send command
>   creates a stream representation of the file system's state. This
>   stream can either describe complete contents of the file system at a
>   given snapshot, or it can be a delta between snapshots. Computing the
>   delta stream is very efficient, and its size depends on the number of
>   blocks changed between the snapshots. This provides an efficient
>   strategy, e.g. for synchronizing offsite backups or high availability
>   mirrors of a pool.

Which filesystems (other than ZFS) supported by linux do have a feature like this?

Is it possible to get something like this with LVM?

Comment: BTRFS can also do it.

Answer (score 1):

The ZFS filesystem is [available on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/) distos. I know a number of people who use it in production though I'm not sure if booting from it is necessarily a good thing on some distros (fedora for example).